# xCode Project template with project file

Tags: ios

I have project template that I am working of, it seems like the project.xcodeproj. Does every template needs to have an project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A XCode 4 template is made from regular files and metadata. The metadata is written in plist files using special instructions from the metadata language. See a sample [here](https://github.com/j4n0/xcode4/blob/master/templates/Project%20Templates/Jano/Window%20Based.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist). The project file is created by XCode after processing a project template. Does this answer your question?